differential equation; $y ' = -2x+3y -5$; find a function or functions for the solution.
Stack Exchange Question Already Asked
I am trying to find a function for the differential equation for $y'=-2x+3y-5$.
There is a jump in the instruction, the question is on Khan Academy. It is known that we want to come up with and solve these equations for $m$ and for $b$, $(3m-2=0)$ and $(3b-5=m)$. Then we can take our answers for $m$ and $b$ and write our function for the differential equation, which is the final answer: $$f(x)=\frac23 x + \frac{17}{9}$$.
In order to find an answer Sal, from Khan Academy uses a linear function to solve. We decide to use the equation $y=mx+b $ and its derivative $y'=\frac{d}{dx}(mx)+\frac{d}{dx}(b)= m$.
The next step in the instruction then is to plug in what we know about the line equation into the differential.  $$y'=-2x+3y-5$$ $$y'= m $$ $$m=-2x+3(mx+b)-5$$ $$m= x(-2+3m)+3b-5$$
At this point in the instruction, we start to understand what $x$ means.  The $x$ must vanish because $m = 3b-5$ is possible.  One rational is m is a constant or not a variable x.  If we want to show this then we can add a $0x$ to the left side.  $$0x+m=x(-2+3m)+3b-5$$  It is like the differential equation now balances out, and we can match the coefficients of $0x$ to both sides.  Now we can see that $m=3b-5$ and $3m-2=0$.  We know $3m-2=0$ because we know $0x(3m-2)=0$.  We solve and substitute our answers into the line function tool kit and get, $$f(x)=\frac23x+\frac{17}{9}$$
My question is why $0x$?  I have a hard time making that jump.  It is not algebraic, $0x +m =x(-2+3m)+3b-5+0x$.  I am crazy slow if I did that.  It took me two years to pass calculus.
Are there any rules or tricks that help when finding solutions for differential equations? Did we have to really prove anything?  It feels like $0x$ is only a start to show we are looking for functions and we are not too concerned with how we come up with our answer, just that we can.  Is that enough to move on to Calculus II?

Different types of differential equations require different tricks. Look at first-order linear equations and integrating factors - that's how I'd solve this one.

I can see the brackets and parentheses are two different functions.  Big epiphany!  It is starting to settle in.  The functions feel very loosely related and hard to pull out.  After all what is -2x + 3y-5?  I have no idea.  Is that a parametric equation or does it just have two variables?

I'll provide another insight to you.
Let $t=-2x+3y$ 
$\implies \frac{dt}{dx}=-2+3\frac{dy}{dx}$
Put this in original equation and get, $$\frac{t'+2}{3}=t-5$$
$$\implies t'=3t-17$$
$$\implies \frac{dt}{3t-17}=dx$$
And don't forget to undo the substitution

Wow thanks.  I will look at this deeper. The choices and substitutions I don’t understand all the way.

or anyone else. Can I get some help with $\frac{dt}{dx}= -2 +3 \frac{dy}{dx}$. I don’t understand how both coefficients remain after differentiation?  How do I start? It seems like $\frac{dt}{dx} = t’ = -2 + 0 $ How does the 3 stay around?  I was taught that when differentiating based on x then any other letter becomes a constant.  How to I venture forward? I am getting something messed up.

@Trig I have used implicit differentiation here. The trick I used here is a classic trick used for questions like these.

@Trig no...when you differentiate wrt x other letters don't become a constant (as you aren't partially differentiating here)...apply chain rule....we have to do differentiation of 3y wrt x ....so pull out 3 as it is a constant...now differentiation of y wrt x is just dy/dx

Where can I learn more about the classic trick?  I need the chain rule slowed down.  The chain rule to me is f'(g(x)*g'(x).  I think I need more Leibniz in my life to get on with it.

Pick a good teacher. I used to prepare for an exam (it's over now and fortunately I cracked it) and learnt all these math topics for that from a good teacher in real life.

Thanks.. I think I have a better understanding.

Implicit differentiation has been very helpful with changing between $\frac{d}{dx} t = \frac{dt}{dx} = t’$. But what does $\frac{dt}{3t-17}=dx$ mean.  The derivative and integral are inverse. Is that what undue means here? Do I use Part 1 of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? $ F(x)=\int f(t)dt$  But I am not sure if this is the right idea or how to put what I am left with back into the integral or how to undue?

$\frac{dt}{3t-17}=dx$ then by integrating both sides we get $\int \frac{dt}{3t-17}=\int dx$ $\implies$ $\frac{\ln(3t-17)}{3}=x+c$ now undo the substitution

Just for quick, ln(x) dx = 1/x.  This is very amazing.  It is nice to see calculus in the wild.  I think the answer is close at hand.  I started talking to the instructor at Roger Williams and taking his Calc 2 class.

I never thought that writing the $\int dx = \int 1 dx$. I found t.  I guess that is the undo that I was missing. I’ll have to try an undo t.

@Trig no...$\ln x dx\ne\frac{1}{x}$ instead $d(\ln x)=\frac{1}{x} dx$

Right now I am lost in the notation and wanted to start from the top.  I was wondering if I integrated right away?  Is this a true statement? $y’=\frac{dy}{dx} = \int -2x+3y-5dx = -(x)^2+3\frac{dy}{dx} +c$ Then this says the $y’=-1(x)^2$ + 3 times the change in y + a constant that we may have lost in integration.
